# Running R script via shell script. syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: bash, shell-script, error-handling, r, syntax

I am currently trying to run an R script via a shell script.

Here the R script:

```
test = rnorm(1:100, 1000)
write.csv(test, 'test.csv')
```

And here the bash script which calls the R one:

```
#!/bin/bash -l
#SBATCH --partition=compute
#SBATCH --job-name=test
#SBATCH --mail-type=ALL
#SBATCH --mail-user=myemail@blabla.com
#SBATCH --time=00:10:00
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --tasks-per-node=12
#SBATCH --account=myaccount
module purge
module load R
${HOME}/test.R
```

I think I did everything correctly, but the output returns the following error:

```
/mydirectory/test.R: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/mydirectory/test.R: line 3: `test = rnorm(1:100, 1000)'
```

Why I did I get this error?

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ${HOME}/test.R`?

Comment: here's the output: -rwxr--r-- 1 username Dec  2 11:37 /mydirectory/test.R

Comment: p.s. if I run test.R without the shell script it works fine.

Comment: @aaaaa: Can you show the complete command, on how you tested the R script to be working?

Comment: it is a 2 lines R script just to see if the shell script works. I just ran it by logging into R and using 'source('test.R')' and it works.

Comment: @aaaaa: Remember, logging into R and running the commands, and trying it out in the shell script is not the same, R shell is different from the bash shell. Figure out a way to run the commands without `logging into R` from the command line directly and use that same approach in the shell script

Comment: yes, just realised that...let's see...

Comment: right..the command is Rscript and it works!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the shell is trying to the run your `${HOME}/test.R` with a `bash` interpreter for which it is not trying to understand the syntax from the line number 3. Use the `R` interpreter explicitly from which you want the `test.R` to run from.

Set the interpreter for your `Rscript` in `test.R` as

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript

module purge
module load R 
test = rnorm(1:100, 1000)
write.csv(test, 'test.csv')
```

This way with the interpreter set, you can now run it from the shell script as

```
Rscript ${HOME}/test.R
```

---

Remember, logging into `R` shell and running the commands on it, and trying it out in the shell script are not the same, `R` shell is different from the `bash` shell. You need to use the way to run the commands without logging into `R` from the command line directly and use that same approach in the shell script.

Comment: I'm quite sure the `module` entries are actually bash functions: http://modules.sourceforge.net/

Comment: After adding the shebang, you can just call the script as `${HOME}/test.R`, you don't need to prepend it with the interpreter anymore

Answer (score 0):

I faced a same issue while running script on Ubuntu container, after replacing the \r\n with \n it works.
Open it the script using a text editor and replace all the \r\n with \n